# How to use raw SET statement when updating records with Eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to use Eloquent to turn the following SQL statement into PHP codes in Laravel?

`UPDATE my_table SET column1 = price*qty*?, column2 = 0 WHERE row_id = ?`

If it's not possible with Eloquent (I couldn't find it in Laravel's documentation), using query builder would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$item = Item::where('row_id', $row_id)->first();
$item->update(['column1' => $item->price * $item->qty, 'column2' => 0]);
```

Comment: I don't think it works. $price and $qty are not data that are given by PHP. They are the price and quantity values of the row that is supposed to be updated by MySQL.